# Ошибка при комите "No syntax errors detected in". Как отключить проверку?

Tags: php, git, symfony, homestead

Файл Group.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Model\Entity;

class Group
{

}
```

Делаю коммит:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/Code/crm.dev$ git commit -m "add: Create class Group"
Checking PHP Lint...
No syntax errors detected in 
/home/vagrant/Code/crm.dev/src/AppBundle/Model/Entity/Group.php
Running Code Sniffer...
/usr/bin/env: ‘php\r’: No such file or directory
Fix the error before commit.
```

Что это за ошибка? Как отключить проверку?

Comment: смотрите хуки гитовые

Comment: @Naumov Спасибо, помогло.